# What's the effect of AsyncLocal<T> in non async/await code?

Tags: c#, async-await, threadstatic

I'm working on a very large and old code base of a desktop winform application. In this code base there are lots of operations performed in background threads, mainly using `BackgroundWorker`.

A common pattern in this code base, is to hide complexity by binding artifacts to the thread being executed. For instance, the database connection and transaction are stored in `[ThreadStatic]` fields.

I'm trying to change this, and start using `async/await` code, and benefit from running the task in any thread of the pool, and allowing a task to continue executing in any other thread by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I know that `[ThreadStatic]` doesn't play nice with `async/await`, and I've read several answers over here suggesting to use `AsyncLocal<T>` instead.

Given that I'm working on a large code base, as mentioned before, I'm unable to switch to `async/await` everywhere in a single shot, and I must do this changes gradually. So the code that before had `[ThreadStatic]` will change to `AsyncLocal<T>`, but large portions of the code will continue using `BackgroundWorker` and won't hit a single `async/await` line of code.

**Question**
Will this work? I need to be able to define some kind of context flow that will work with my new `async/await` code, and also keep working with my old non async code which relied on `[ThreadStatic]` keeping every thread stuff independent from each other.

If I'm totally wrong and going down the wrong path, suggestions are very welcomed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It should work.

`AsyncLocal<T>` is an abstraction of the logical call context. I describe [the logical call context and how it interacts with `async`/`await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) in detail in an old blog post.

In summary, it will probably work fine, but there is one aspect of `AsyncLocal<T>` that is quite different than `ThreadStatic`.

When you write to the `AsyncLocal<T>` value, that value is set for the current logical call context. An `async` method will establish a copy-on-write scope for its logical call context, so if you write to it *within* an `async` method, it will create a *new* logical call context that contains the new value. This allows `async` method to use it in a nested fashion, where "inner" contexts can overwrite "outer" contexts. *However,* the "inner" context values never flow back to the caller; when the "outer" context is resumed, it completely replaces the "inner" context.

If none of the methods are `async` and the values are only set from their own threads, then that thread just has a single logical call context, and writing/reading the values will work just the same as `ThreadStatic`.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959816/901333) a very detailed explanation for `AsyncLocal<T>` but I will try to simplify it and also show how to make mentioned behavior of `AsyncLocal<T>` nested contexts the same as `ThreadStatic` if necessary.

So simply speaking the value of type `T` in `AsyncLocal<T>` is copied **by value** to every inner logical call context. This is similar to passing some simple value parameter (for example `int`) to nested sub-functions. Changing its value in any sub-function will never affect the value in the caller function.

But in some cases for example, when creating fakes for asynchronous tests you need to change this behavior of `AsyncLocal<T>` (and have it the same as `ThreadStatic`). As a workaround, you can use a wrapper class holding the target value:

```
public class SimpleWrapper<T>
{
    public T? Value { set; get; }

    public SimpleWrapper()
    {
    }

    public SimpleWrapper(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

and then use it instead of `T` like this:

```
private static readonly AsyncLocal<SimpleWrapper<int>> Counter = new();
```

In this example, you can change the `Counter.Value.Value` at any time and this will affect all logical call contexts in the current async flow.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Did you mean "you can change the `Counter.Value.Value` at any time and this will affect all logical call contexts" by any chance?

Comment: Of course `Counter.Value.Value`. Thanks! Fixed